# Script Loaded in Wordpress but won't run

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm a beginner to WordPress and coding/web development as a whole so I'm not 100% where the problem is coming from but I have a general idea.

I'm trying to add a sticky sidebar that sticks after the user has scrolled past it but it's just not working right. I added a javascript file with my code to my theme's folder and ran the wp_enque as follows:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('test-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Test-script.js', array(), true);
    wp_enqueue_script('test-script');
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts', 999 );
```

When viewing the page source, I can see that wordpress is pulling test-script.js but nothing's happening. I pulled the code for the script straight from w3schools:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Where is the issue here? Is there some variable or something that I'm missing in the js file or did I enque it incorrectly?

Comment: Have you checked the browsers dev tools console for errors? Are you sure that the navbar element HTML has been recieved yet when your call happens?

Comment: If the script is being loaded by WordPress, then everything that happens after that is purely a JavaScript question, so you'd be better off asking on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @TomJNowell Oh my gosh I didn't even know you could use the console tools to effectively debug. Thank you! It seems that the initial error was that I got the url for the script wrong in the enque but now I'm receiving these errors: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at testFunction and at window.onscroll

Comment: So clearly `navbar` is null, perhaps `navbar` is not present on the page yet ( the page doesn't arrive all at once instantly, JS can run before the page has finished transferring from the server, and _before the DOM is ready *hint hint*_), perhaps it's actually `navigationbar`, who knows, but I do know that this is not a WordPress question. You should have asked this on stack overflow

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll direct further questions on this topic to stack overflow